# Fastest way to fetch tags and status of GCE instances?

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud

When I perform 3D graphics rendering using GCE Linux instances (CPU load >= 1.0), the `describe` command takes more than 30 seconds to execute.

```
gcloud compute instances describe render-1
```

When running 50 such instances and querying each one individually, this takes more than 25 minutes.

Is there a faster way to fetch this data?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`gcloud compute instances list` should do what you want. In order to get information on tags and status, you'll want to use the `--format` flag:

```
$ gcloud compute instances list --format=json
[...]
$ gcloud compute instances list --format='table(name,status,tags.list())'
NAME                              STATUS      TAGS
instance-name                     RUNNING     fingerprint=AAAAAAAAAAA=
instance-2-name                   RUNNING     fingerprint=AAAAAAAAAAA=,items=[u'http-server', u'https-server']
```

Take a look at the output of `gcloud topic formats` and `gcloud topic projections` for more information on formatting.

Comment: Excellent, what a difference! It now takes roughly 15-30 seconds to query all of my instances in one go. The JSON output format was super helpful as well.