# GCP : gcloud :List all instances along with their tag names

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I am executing the below command to get the list of all instances in a GCP project, but this doesn't display the tags attached to the VMs..!
FYI..

```
gcloud compute instances list
```

Could you please help here..!

Regards,
Rohith

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fastest way to fetch tags and status of GCE instances?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37047089/fastest-way-to-fetch-tags-and-status-of-gce-instances)

Comment: Yup..! Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Get the detailed output using `gcloud` topic formats:

```
gcloud compute instances list --format=json
```

Or

```
gcloud compute instances list --format='table(name,status,tags.list())'
```