# How to get all instance with a tag number in GCP compute engine

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I want to get all instance id or list of all instance based on tag in GCP compute engine using Google compute engine sdk.

Can someone guide me how i can do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can filter results from list commands with regular expressions by including the [--filter](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/filters) flag as shown in this official GCP [document](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/add-tags).

Use the **filter** in command as shown below:

**`“gcloud compute instances list --filter="tags:tag1"”`**

Replace “**tag1**” in the above command with the tag you have used for your instances so that you will get only instances with the mentioned tag.

Comment: Check this similar [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37047089/) for more insights.